# Insertar un elemento HTML dentro del primeri hijo TD de un TR con classe XXX

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Quiero en el siguiente codigo, mover el elemento .buscarusuarios dentro del primer TD hijo del TR classe fltrow, una vez que se inicie el dom. Ando un poco perdido con los selectores de CSS3

```
<form class="buscarusuarios">
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()"  
type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">     
</form>

<tr class="fltrow">
<td>Prueba</td>
<td>Prueba</td>
<td>Prueba</td>
<td>Prueba</td>
<td>Prueba</td>       
</tr>
```

Comment: Puedes hacerlo de las dos maneras, si pones el código te puedo echar una mano a entender el cómo se debería hacer

Comment: Cambie la descripcion e inclui el texto ahora en la pregunta.

La tabla es creada dinamicamente por otro complemento que hace filtros, pero la primera celda la dejo vacia, y necesito insertar ese elemento en ella, que lo tengo fuera de la tabla.

estoy haciendo algo al estilo :

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.buscarusuarios').appendTo('.fltrow');
    });

pero lo esta insertando dentro del TR, y yo quiero que lo ponga dentro del primer TD de esse TR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No me ha quedado claro lo que necesitabas meter en la tabla, pero he añadido el formulario con el search.

Lo que necesitabas era la propiedad `td:first-child` que selecciona el primer elemento `td` 
dentro de la fila `tr`.

Para un futuro también te recomiendo mirar los `:nth-child(1)` ya que con esto puedes conseguir el mismo propósito y además este te permite elegir la posición en la que quieres añadirlo (1,2,3,4,5,6...).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
  <tr class="fltrow">
   <td>Prueba</td>
   <td>Prueba</td>
   <td>Prueba</td>
   <td>Prueba</td>
   <td>Prueba</td>       
  </tr>
 </table>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    var form = '<form class="buscarusuarios"><input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()"type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"></form>';

    $('.fltrow').children('td:first-child').html(form);
   
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que con esto te quede claro como funciona.

Comment: Show, está súper excelente, me sirvio perfectamente. :-)